# Tool to automatically covert a text string with special characters to a properly formatted c# string

Tags: c#

I had this really useful app in VB6 & I was wondering if anyone knows of an equivalent one for c#...

Basically the vb6 app allowed you to paste text into an input box and then it would produce an output text that was correctly formatted (with special characters) so that you could paste it directly in your code without having to convert special characters.

For example...

**Input**

Say "Hello"

**Output**

```
string s = "Say \"Hello\"";
```

If anyone know of an equivalent free tool for c#, or something I can do in VS2008 that would avoid me having to do this process manually, it would be appreciated!

Comment: Even the example you give isn't properly formatted - inside a string prefixed with `@` you escape a double quote as `""` not `\"`.

Comment: @David: I think you just proved just how useful that little app might be...

Comment: Now you see my problem... lol... thanks, I changed it... I really do need this tool

Comment: Seems like it would have been faster to write this app than to ask the question.

Comment: Lol... well the Smart paster app was what I was looking for.. it's pretty cool if you ask me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Smart Paster](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2004/05/25/Smart-Paster-1.1-Add-In---StringBuilder-and-Better-C_2300_-Handling.aspx) add-in.
It allows you to paste the text in the clipboard in various formats, and does this kind of escaping for you.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for orsogufo! That is going to be a real timesaver...

Answer (score 2):

The 99% solution is a one-liner:

return "\"" + textBox1.Text.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("\"", "\"") + "\"";

Comment: Thanks nobugz... but when I try and paste this code into a c# project I get an error

e.g. 
public string Convert(string input)
{
            return "\"" + input.Replace("\", "\\").Replace("\"", "\"") + "\"";
}

Answer (score 2):

[The C# language specification says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx) that the only special character in a verbatim string literal  (`@"..."`) is the double quote (`"`), which can be escaped by duplicating it (`""`). So, the algorithm you want is quite simple (untested, beware of typos):

```
outputTextBox.Text = "string s = @\"" + inputTextBox.Text.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\";";
```

Example:

```
a       => string s = @"a";
a "b" c => string s = @"a ""b"" c";
a\b c   => string s = @"a\b c";
```

Since verbatim string literals support linebreaks, this should even work for multi-line text.

*(Actually, since the only character you need to escape is the double quote, I'm wondering whether it's even worth writing this program.)*

Answer (score 1):

nobugz's solution works fine for a single line of text, but you'd need to change it to be able to cope with multiple lines:

```
text = text.Replace("\r", @"\r").Replace("\n", @"\n");
text = text.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
return "\"" + text + "\"";
```

Or if you want a verbatim literal then you need only escape quotes:

```
text = text.Replace("\"", "\"\"")
return "@\"" + text + "\"";
```